# Querying SecureSocial for currently signed-in users

Tags: playframework, securesocial

Is there a way to know **which users are currently signed in** with a Playframework application using the **Secure Social API**? If so how?

More generally **where and how are currently signed-in users stored** in a Play/SecureSocial application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SecureSocial keeps track of authenticated users using the the AuthenticatorStore plugin.  The default implementation uses the Play cache but you can create your own.  If you create your own implementation then you can decide where to save the session and then query that to find out what you need.

Another approach could be to write an EventListener. SecureSocial fires Login and Logout events. You can persist those events and that would also give you the active users. You can however loose logout events in this case if the user just closes the browser.  I'd say relying in the AuthenticatorStore is more reliable because Authenticators have an expiration that you can check when running a query.

Comment: Does this means that with the default AuthenticatorStore, users could be logged out if their cache entry expires? AFAIK both default and memcached implementations will remove old entries if they run out of memory.

Comment: Yes, entries are supposed to expire after the absolute timeout has passed.  As of removing entries due to low memory or some other configuration constraint you are also right, that could happen and should be taken into consideration if the cache is being used a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Play Framework 2 ?

If so, you can create your own `UserService`, as explained in the documentation : http://securesocial.ws/guide/user-service.html

You can then implement the `find(Identity)` (in Scala), or `doFind(Identity)` (in Java)  method and choose how to log and store users.

In fact, in these methods, you must log the user depending of the way he connected (Twitter, Facebook ...).

You then also have to implement the `save(Identity)` (in Scala), or `doSave(Identity)` method in order to store a user when he creates an account or log for the first time with a specific social network.

If you provide a way to log in with username//password, you must implement the `findByEmailAndProvider` (in Scala) or `doFindByEmailAndProvider` method.

So, if you control the way users connect to your site, you can store (and retrieve) the connected users.

Comment: Thanks Zarkus. Yes I do use Play 2. Where do you advise I store/save the currently connected users? Redis? MongoDB? HttpSession?

Comment: It all depends on your architecture. I guess that if you already use a database (SQL or NoSQL, MySQL or MongoDB, or even Redis), you should continue to use it. But if you don't, prefer something like the cache system with MemCache for example, because of the immutability and stateless caracteristics of Play (so don't use session or application storage). Hope it will help you ;)

Comment: Another of my concerns is what happens if a user does not logout but leaves the app: will they still live in Redis/Memcache and if so how long for?

Comment: Yes the user will still be stored. The delay before it is deleted will depend on how you implement it. You can for example set a timeout (30 minutes), updated each time the user requests the server, and a batch service that automatically delete expired users.